# Headings in-line with image

Tags: html, css, positioning

I am trying to get the top of a website to look like this:

[image: Photoshop Design]

But it looks like this:

[image: Finished]

And here is the code:

```css
.navigationbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 11%;
  background-color: #202020;
  padding-top: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.logo {
  margin-left: 20%;
  height: 85%;
  width: 19.3%;
  margin-top: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}
.navigationbar ul {} .navigationbar li {
  margin-right: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  width: 0%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.navigationbar li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigationbar">

  <img src="images/Logo.png" alt="Logo" class="logo">

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About Me</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Ignore the other problems, such as the height and the logo, and also the font for the headings.  I am just trying to position them correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, try removing the floats..they are incompatible with inline-block which is the way to do this as it supports `vertical-align:middle`

I think you are most of the way there already.

```css
.navigationbar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 11%;
  background-color: #202020;
  padding-top: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.logo {
  margin-left: 20%;
  height: 85%;
  width: 19.3%;
  margin-top: 8px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle /* line up with other siblings */
}
.navigationbar ul {
  display: inline-block; 
  vertical-align: middle /* now lined up with logo */
}
.navigationbar li {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 10px;
  vertical-align: middle; /* line up the list items */
}
.navigationbar li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

```html
<div class="navigationbar">

  <img src="images/Logo.png" alt="Logo" class="logo">

  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About Me</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact Me</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Works fine, thanks!  How would I get the headings to go to the right of the div though?

Comment: That's a little harder and probably would require me rejigging some of the structure.

Comment: In that case, I'd do something like this...it's quick and dirty so could use some tweaking - http://jsfiddle.net/Paulie_D/4j9njfwx/ Note, I'm not using `inline-block` now quite so much.

Comment: I have done this now, but I can't apply a margin to the headings without them messing up, and the logo is distorted.

Comment: I'm offering solutions to your stated **original** question. If you need additional assistance perhaps you need to decide one which method you wish to use and ask another **separate** question regarding specific issues.